# OpenMP: Race condition within single region between barriers

Tags: c++, openmp, shared-memory, race-condition

Consider the following code extract, part of a larger code:

```
201     for (int iMesh = _meshByThread[iThread][0]; iMesh <= _meshByThread[iThread][1]; iMesh++){
202         _eq[iMesh]->updateDataPreBC(*_sol[iMesh], t);
203     }
204 #pragma omp barrier
205 #pragma omp single
206     {
207         for (size_t iBC = 0; iBC < _bndConditions.size(); iBC++)
208             _bndConditions[iBC]->apply(_sol, t);
209     }
```

Intel Inspector reports a data race, with the following output:

[image: Intel Inspector Output]

You may want a complete example, but I do not think that it is needed given my simple question:

As there is an explicit barrier before the single region and an implicit barrier at the end of the single region, if a thread is inside the single region, all the other threads should be between these two barriers, right?

In other words, is it possible that one thread is on line 208 (inside the single region), while the other thread is on line 202 (outside of the single region) as Intel Inspector says? If not, it is a false positive (or undefined behavior to fix, occurring somewhere else in the code).

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: This is Intel Inspector output, with graphical information such as thread number and location. As I specifically question Intel Inspector output, I thought it would be more appropriate.

Comment: basically no - but you could have undefined behavior anywhere in the code suddenly anything is possible. Try reproducing the Intel Inspector output with a [mcve]. Then we can properly discuss it here.

Comment: Thanks Zulan, this answers my question. Then false positive OR undefined behavior due to a bug somewhere in my code. Unfortunately, this is a big code and I was not able to reproduce it in a minimal example, so I guess there should be something wrong somewhere in my code.